# C++ delete a class pointer & polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I am learning about polymorphism, and this is something I have stumbled on. I cant find satisfying answer and testing the following code doesnt yield expected result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
        Base(){
            std::cout<<"Constructing Base" << std::endl;
        };
        virtual int get_a(){
            return p_a;
        };
        virtual int check(){
            std::cout<<"check Base" << std::endl; return 2;
        };
        virtual ~Base(){
            std::cout<<"Destroying Base" << std::endl;
        };
        int p_a = 4;
};

class Derive: public Base {
    public:
        Derive(){
            std::cout<<"Constructing Derive" << std::endl;
        };
        int get_a(){
            return p_a;
        };
        int check(){
            std::cout<<"check Derive" << std::endl;
            return 3;
        };
        ~Derive(){ std::cout<<"Destroying Derive" << std::endl; };
        int p_a = 2;
 };

int main() {
        Base *basePtr = new Derive();
        delete basePtr;
        basePtr->check();
        std::cout << "p_a: " << basePtr->get_a() << std::endl;
        return 1;
}
```

Console output :

```
Constructing Base    // line 1
Constructing Derive  // line 2
Destroying Derive    // line 3
Destroying Base      // line 4
check Base           // line 5
p_a: 4               // line 6
```

I see why I get line 1-4, the basePtr is pointer to Derive, which inherits from Base, which implements virtual functions.

My 1. expectation : After calling **delete**, the pointer basePtr should not be able to deliver the function call ->check(), and also there should be no value p_a.

My 2. expectation : I would expect the value *p_a* from Derive (p_a = 2), to appear on the output, because basePtr stores the pointer of Derive.

Could someone correct my thinking ?

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to always set pointer you just deleted to nullptr.

Comment: *The pointer basePtr should not be able to deliver the function call ->check(),* -- Why not?  Your code says to do that, and that's what happened.  If you tell C++ to do something, it does it, whether or not what you're asking it to do may need to undesirable results.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld: Uhm... this is why you **don't** use pointers in C++ at all. Objects with automatic storage duration are great, including smart pointer types like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes you're right, not a single professional library/C++ API ever uses pointers so yeah, you'll never ever have to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. Whatever results you get, are invalid.

```
delete basePtr;
```

This destroys the object.

```
basePtr->check();
```

After destroying the object, the shown code attempts to dereference a pointer to the destroyed instance of the class, and invoke a method of the destroyed object. Invoking a method of a destroyed object is undefined behavior.